# JSON.net Array diff in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have two arrays

```
"commanditaires_data": [
    {
        "id": "254",
        "level": 78
    },
    {
        "id": "255",
        "level": 22
    }
]

"commanditaires_data": [
    {
        "id": "254",
        "level": 78
    }, {
        "id": "255",
        "level": 22
    },
    {
        "id": "255",
        "level": 22
    }
]
```

I don't manage to get the missing items in the first array.

I need to do a differential between these two arrays.

I tried to use Except() but I send me every items of the first arrays

I'm using JSON.NET so my vars for arrays  are :

```
var srcObjs = source.Children().ToList().OfType<JObject>();
var tarObjs = target.Children().ToList().OfType<JObject>();

var diff = tarObjs.Except(src.objs);
```

=> It sends me all items in tarObjs.

I need to handle many cases :

```
 If srcObjs.Count() < tarObjs.Count() //Added item(s)
 If srcObjs.Count() > tarObjs.Count() // Deleted item(s)
 Else //Edited Item(s)
```

I also tried to use linq but without success

Comment: Try using except but with custom equality comparers.

Comment: I can't compare on properties, because I have objects with dynamic properties, so I can't put hard coded property name. I need to detect for the first case which objects in the target array aren't in the source array

Comment: If you have dinamic properties ...what are you comparing then? Only on count?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CommanditairesEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<Commanditaires>
    {

        public bool Equals(Commanditaires first, Commanditaires second)
        {
            if (first== null && first== null)
                return true;

            return first.Id == second.Id
                && first.Level == second.Level;
        }    

        public int GetHashCode(Commanditaires model)
        {
            return model.Id.GetHashCode() + model.Level.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

and then

```
var comparer = new CommanditairesEqualityComparer();
var distinctItems = firstList.Except(secondList, comparer );
```